# Minimum bounding geometry outputs in meters

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, extents

Which CRS is best to use on QGIS to get the minimum bounding geography outputs to present in meters?

I need the length and width measurements of > 1000 polygons, but can figure how to get the outputs in meters.

Comment: Getting the outputs in meters (or feet) requires your input layer to be in a projected coordinate system. Use the tool 'reproject' to reproject from a geographic coordinate system (EPSG 4326 presumably) to a projected coordinate system (EPSG 32643 I'm assuming based on your project CRS), then run the Bounding geometry algorithm